# ASP UpdatePanel Throws Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, updatepanel

I have an ASP page which has a **GridView** and a button for searching. When I press the button a request is sent to a WCF service, which will return 100,000 or more entries. I am using an **UpdatePAnel** so it is only the **GridView** that is updated(To avoid the whole page to refresh).it works perfectly the first time. If I press my button second time i get

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException.
```

I have tried to to add the following code as well:

```
 <%--            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
            function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                if (args.get_error() != undefined) {
                    args.set_errorHandled(true);
                }
            }
        </script>--%>
```

and i have also set `ValidateRequest="false"`. 
Please help me.

here is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="AutoLogGridViewUpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="AlarmLogGrideView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EquipmentID" HeaderText="Equipment ID" SortExpression="EquipmentID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Start" HeaderText="Start" SortExpression="Start" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="End" HeaderText="End" SortExpression="End" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Show" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Search2" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: it would be better if u can show your .aspx page. Try after adding in AsyncPostBackTrigger in updatePanel as <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefresh" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>

Comment: i have done that. I uploaded my .aspx code

Comment: The same code which I executed just now is working fine.. issue might be with large data size. try changing in web.config file 

<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="100,001" />
 </appSettings>

Comment: I tried that. Plus we tried increasing `MaxRequestLEngth` value. Now I get **OutOfMemoryException**.

Comment: Probably getting 100,000 records is not ri8 way. first try with less number of records some thing like  100 or 200 if that works fine then you should change the way u bind data to  Grid

Comment: ty very much. I tried to change the gridview to show in received data in pages. Fixed the problem. I just need to figure out a way, to stop the gridview call on Page_Load every time i change the page.